# Expanding tableview cell data being overwritten when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a transaction tableview with different types of expenses that expands to show more detail when selected.

However the detail appears to be overwritten when this happens. I can see it flash and sometimes it does get populated. The textfields get populated correctly. I have been trying to debug this for a while, but not sure how to work around this problem.

Here is my current implementation:

```
// MARK: Tableview
extension TransactionViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - Table View

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        var isDetailHidden = true
        if indexPath.row == rowSelected {
            isDetailHidden = false
        }
        let transaction = transactionList[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(transaction: transaction, isDetailHidden: isDetailHidden)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return transactionList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == rowSelected {
        // don't refresh and set again.
        return
    }

    rowSelected = indexPath.row
    transactionBeingEdited = transactionList[indexPath.row]

    transactionTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: rowSelected! * 76), animated: true)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.configureDetailCell()
    transactionTableView.reloadData()
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let transaction = transactionList[indexPath.row]
        coreDataManager.deleteTransaction(transaction: transaction)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row != rowSelected {
            return 76.5
        } else {
            return 323
        }
    }
```

The variables in the detail section are dropdown boxes using a library. I've configured it in the UITableViewCell class. Setting up the dropdown methods occurs in the awakefromnib method.

```
private func setupBillDropDown() {
        billDropDown.anchorView = bill
        billDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bill.bounds.height)
        billDropDown.dataSource = TransactionType.list

        // Action triggered on selection
        billDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
            self.bill.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
            self.bill.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)

            // Update transaction
            if let transactionBeingEdited = self.delegate?.transactionBeingEdited {
                transactionBeingEdited.type = item
                self.coreDataManager.saveToCoreData()
                self.coreDataManager.nc.post(name: .transactionBeingEdited, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) you are overwriting the configured cell by loading the table. Try this:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
if indexPath.row == rowSelected {
    // don't refresh and set again.
    return
}

rowSelected = indexPath.row
transactionBeingEdited = transactionList[indexPath.row]

transactionTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: rowSelected! * 76), animated: true)

//let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell.configureDetailCell()
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I'm thinking it has to do with the dropdown fields because the two textfields in the details section aren't being overwritten. I've tried moving the dropdown methods to different spots in the code but that doesn't fix the issue either :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue after spending literally hours on it... It's because I was updating the buttons title using

```
bill.titleLabel!.text = transaction.type ?? "Select Bill"
```

insteaad of

```
bill.setTitle(transaction.type ?? "Select Bill", for: .normal)
```